# I keep getting http/1.0 400 json rpc error with c++

Tags: c++, json, curl

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t WriteCallback(char *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

CURL* easyhandle = curl_easy_init();
std::string readBuffer;

curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.79:8080");
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"{ \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"get\", \"params\": [\"Frozen\"], \"id\": 3}");
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);

curl_easy_perform(easyhandle);

std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
//std::cout << "{ \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"getTitles\", \"params\": [clea], \"id\": 3}" << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Here is my code for my curl command. I see the request come through on my server but it keeps saying rpc error. I think it is the way i am formatting my json. Basically on my pc if I run this curl command in terminal it works. However, running it in c++ is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out "Frozen" was not in the library. After adding it on the server it worked.